# How to calculate specificity for multiclass problems using Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, metrics, precision-recall

I have been searching around for a Scikit-learn package which calculates the specificity for multiclass problems but I can't seem to find one.

I had a looked at `sklearn.metrics.recall_score` but this package does not calculate the specificity for multiclass problems, in particular setting `pos_label=0` does not work for the multiclass case.

`sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support` and `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` also doesn't appear to support the calculation of specificity for multiclass problems.

If Scikit-learn intentionally did not include the specificity for multiclass problems in their packages, is there a reason in doing so?